# PyCharm: activate venv when running a script

Tags: python, pycharm, runtime, virtualenv

I am new in PyCharm, I use the 2019 CE version.

I have set an environment variable in `venv/bin/activate`:

```
# User defined variables:
export DATABASE="postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres"
```

And I can access it using bash:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ echo $DATABASE
postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres
```

And when running my script in this environment, it works as expected:

```
(venv) $ python3 newproject/settings.py 
{'database': 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres'}
```

It is also automatically done for PyCharm Terminal that natively activates the environment, but I could not succeed in setting it when I run a script.

Anyway, when I specify a Run Configuration to execute a script that needs to access this environment variable, the environment is not loaded automatically before running the script. I have searched almost everywhere, the logical place should be there:

[image]

I have found no option (or documentation) to enable `virtualenv` before running a script. I even tried to add an external tool to manually activate it before it runs the script. But it is useless since executed environments are disjoint: the script does not run in the same environment that `venv`.

Looking at the python interpreter it seems it is the correct environment.

[image]

I know that I can set Environment Variable in this peculiar setup form, but then variables are no longer available when I run the virtual environment, so it is not a solution to me.

My question is then: **How can I setup a Run Configuration that activate my environment and run the script within this environment?**

Comment: Have you checked the settings in [project interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)?

Comment: @arsho Yes I have read this page twice, but there is few options in my GUI, and none allows me to activate the environment

Comment: If  your script is running, it is running under an interpreter. That interpreter has already been selected by your `venv` settings. The script that is running under one interpreter can't arrange to switch to a new interpreter because at that point the choice of interpreter has already been made. After the gun has been fired for the 100m sprint you are running in, it's too late to decide that you really wanted to sign up for a different event.

Comment: @BoarGules, Yes I conceive that, but then How can I make `./venv/bin/python3` aware of environment variable I have set in `./venv/bin/activate`? There is no activation option in PyCharm dialogs.